# Flawed understanding of independent events

Tags: probability, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, independence

Suppose we pick a bit string of length 4 at random, all bit strings equally likely. Consider the following
events:

$E_1$: the string begins with 1.

$E_2$: the string ends with 1.

$E_3$: the string has exactly two 1’s

Are $E_1$ and $E_2$ independent? Justify your answer.

My reasoning was that:

$Pr(E_2) * Pr(E_1) = .5 * .5 = .25$

$Pr(E_1∩E_2) =$ $4\choose2$$.5^2*.5^2 = .375$

$.375$ does not equal $.25$, so I said they were not independent. However, the states:

Yes, $Pr(E_1 ∩ E_2) = .25 =.5 * .5 = Pr(E_1) * Pr(E_2)$

I was wondering why my reasoning was flawed?

Comment: Your computation of $P(E_1\cap E_2)$ seems to involve conditions related to $E_3$?

Comment: Your calculation of $P(E_1\land E_2)$ is mistaken. What you have calculated instead is the prob. that exactly $2$ of the $4$ bits are $1$'s. Another  way to infer independence is to get $P(A)=P(A|B)$ and $P(B)=P(B|A$). If you toss  4 coins  $c_1,c_2,c_3,c_4$,does the outcome of the  toss of any one coin affect the odds of the outcome of any other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My reasoning was that:
>
> $\Pr(E_2) \cdot \Pr(E_1) = 0.5 \cdot 0.5 = 0.25$
>
> $\Pr(E_1\cap E_2) = {4\choose 2}\cdot 0.5^2\cdot 0.5^2 = .375$

The first is correct, but the second is in error.

What you have calculated the the probability of having exactly two `1` anywhere in the bit string (and two `0` elsewhere).   That isn't what you wanted.   This is actually: $\Pr(E_3)$

$$E_3~\neq~ E_1\cap E_2$$

What you needed to calculate was the probability of having `1` in the first and last positions and anything in the middle two positions.
$$\begin{array}{rcl}\Pr(E_1) =& 0.5\cdot 1\cdot 1\cdot 1~~~ &= 0.5 \\ \Pr(E_2) =& ~~~1\cdot 1\cdot 1\cdot 0.5 &= 0.5 \\ \Pr(E_1\cap E_2) =& 0.5\cdot 1\cdot 1\cdot 0.5 &= 0.25\end{array}$$

Now, as stated, you have found $\Pr(E_3)$ and similarly we find:

$$\begin{array}{rcl}\Pr(E_3) =& \binom{4}{2}\cdot 0.5^4 &= 0.375 \\ \Pr(E_1\cap E_3) =& \binom{3}{1}\cdot 0.5^4 &= 0.1875 \\ \Pr(E_2\cap E_3) =& \binom{3}{1}\cdot 0.5^4 &= 0.1875 \\ \Pr(E_1\cap E_2\cap E_3) =& ~~~~~~0.5^4 &= 0.0625\end{array}$$

So, what does this all tell you about the independencies of the three events?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure that your *understanding of independence* is flawed, it's just your calculation of $P(E_1\cap E_2)$.  To choose a string in $E_1\cap E_2$ you have to choose the second digit ($2$ possibilities) and choose the third digit ($2$ possibilities).  So there are $2^2$ strings, not $\binom42$, and we get
$$P(E_1\cap E_2)=2^2(0.5)^2(0.5)^2=0.25\ .$$

Answer (score 0):

It's not that hard to look at all possible strings. There are $2^4= 16$ "bit strings of length 4".  The are 
0000, 0001, 0010, 0011, 0100, 0101, 0110, 0111,
1000, 1001, 1010, 1011, 1100, 1101, 1110, 1111.

"E1: the string begins with 1"
  Okay there are 8 of those: 
1000, 1001, 1010, 1011, 1100, 1101, 1110, 1111.

"E2: the string ends with 1."
There are 8 of those:
0001, 0011, 0101, 0111, 1001, 1011, 1101, 1111.

4 of the strings in E1 also end with a "1" so P(E2)= 8/16= 1/2 and P(E2| E1)= 4/8= 1/2.  Those are equal so E1 and E2 are independent.

E3: the string has exactly two 1’s"
there are $\begin{pmatrix}4 \\ 2 \end{pmatrix}= \frac{4!}{2!2!}= 6$ of them
0011, 0101, 0110, 1001, 1010, 1100.